# How to navigate inside an array using addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, arrays, addeventlistener

I'm trying to setup a slider for a project. I have an array of objects, every object contains an image and a legend. Every time a user clicks next or previous button it should display the next or previous object of the array. Problem is it displays the same image instead of the next, the third, fifth and so on.

```
var index = 0;
var images = [
    {image: 'images/1.jpg', legend: 'Street Art'},
    {image: 'images/2.jpg', legend: 'Fast Lane'},
    {image: 'images/3.jpg', legend: 'Colorful Building'},
    {image: 'images/4.jpg', legend: 'Skyscrapers'},
    {image: 'images/5.jpg', legend: 'City by night'},
    {image: 'images/6.jpg', legend: 'Tour Eiffel la nuit'}
];
var previous = document.getElementById('slider-previous');
var next = document.getElementById('slider-next');

next.addEventListener('click', function() {
    img.src= images[index++].image;
    figcaption.textContent = images[index++].legend;
});
previous.addEventListener('click', function() {
    img.src= images[index--].image;
    figcaption.textContent = images[index--].legend;
});
```

Comment: Only increment / decrement `index` **once** in each event handler. Also, you want to prefix `index` with the appropriate operator instead of using a suffix, ie `++index`

Comment: you should post a simple fiddle, your code looks like it should work (albeit skip a image because you increment twice)

Comment: `index++` returns the value first and then increment it. `++index` increments it first and then returns the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works way better, thanks Phil

```
next.addEventListener('click', function() {
    ++index;
    img.src= images[index].image;
    figcaption.textContent = images[index].legend;
});

previous.addEventListener('click', function() {
    --index;
    img.src= images[index].image;
    figcaption.textContent = images[index].legend;
});
```